# [html, php, mysql]How to get previous row base on current row dynamically with an input or button and display in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am constructing a forum now and I will have a navbar with a button "edit" for the user to edit their previous comment.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="#quest"> Post a Question</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#edit"> Edit comment</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="userprofile.php" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <?php echo $username;?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is how I display all comments posted before on the pages, but I don't know if it will help or not.

```
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
                $id = $_GET['post_id'];
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblpost as tp join category as c on tp.cat_id=c.cat_id where tp.post_Id='$id' ");
                if($sql==true){
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                        extract($row);
                        if($user_Id==009){
                            echo "<label>Topic Title: </label> ".$title."<br>";
                            echo "<label>Topic Category: </label> ".$category."<br>";
                            echo "<label>Date time posted: </label> ".$datetime;
                            echo "<p class='well'>".$content."</p>";
                            echo "<label>Posted By: </label> Admin";
                        }else{
                            $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbluser where user_Id='$user_Id' ");
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sel)){
                                extract($row);
                                echo "<label>Topic Title: </label> ".$title."<br>";
                                echo "<label>Topic Category: </label> ".$category."<br>";
                                echo "<label>Date time posted: </label> ".$datetime;
                                echo "<p class='well'>".$content."</p>";
                                echo '<label>Posted By: </label>'.$fname.' '.$lname;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

But currently I can only let the user to edit their most recent comment since I can't figure out a way for to display the previous row of comment based on current row of comment. And below is the part to handle it. It will be like a little popup screen and a text-area displaying the most recent comment and user can update it.

```
<div class="my-quest" id="edit">
    <div>
        <h3>Edit Comment</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="editcomment.php">
            <?php
                $postid= $_GET['post_id'];
                $comment = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblcomment as c join tbluser as u on c.user_Id=u.user_Id where post_Id='$postid' and comment_Id in ( select max(comment_Id) from tblcomment)");
                $rowedit=mysql_fetch_assoc($comment)
            ?>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="editcommenttxt"><?php echo $rowedit['comment']?></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="editpostid" value="<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="edituserid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_Id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="editcomment" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Edit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <a href="" class="pull-right">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the user finished his editing, the post value will be sent to editcomment.php and bunch of sql work. Here is the code to do it.

```
<?php 
include "../functions/db.php";
if(isset($_POST['editcomment'])){
    extract($_POST);

    $check = mysql_query("select max(comment_Id) as maxid from tblcomment where user_Id = '$edituserid'");
    $check2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
    $sql = "Update tblcomment set comment='$editcommenttxt' where post_Id = '$editpostid' and comment_Id = '".$check2['maxid']."'";

    $update=mysql_query($sql);

    if($update==true) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Post Successfully")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=content.php?post_id='.$editpostid.'" />';
    } else {
        echo "Sorry error occur, cannot edit post!";
    }
}
?>
```

The title is just one of my idea to partially achieve my goal (at least not limited to latest one), any other method that can allow user to edit specified comment will also be accepted. The forum is just a small project for myself to learn more. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you update from `mysql` to `mysqli` as `mysql` is depreciated. Also putting the `$id` variable into the SQL query without cleaning/checking it puts your database at risk of **SQL injections**. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: i know about the real_escape_string() and strip_tag() function for security purpose, but that wasnt my focus now since it will be in my localhost only...